# window.location.assign with AJAX in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have the following AJAX POST request which sends serialized form data to the server:

```
// Handle form submission.
$('#evaluationform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    ajaxObject = {
        url: $("#evaluationform").attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        data: $("#evaluationform").serialize(),
    };

    $.ajax(ajaxObject)
        .success(function(data,status,xhr) {
            window.location.assign("http://example.com/survey/instruction/thankyou.html");
        })
        .fail(function(data,status,xhr) {
            window.location.assign("http://example.com/survey/instruction/fail.html");
        })
        .always(function(data,status,xhr) {
            console.log(status);
        });
});
```

While the assign path is followed in Chrome and Safari, it is not in Firefox. The assign is ignored in Firefox and instead spits me out to the API URL as defined in my form's action attribute.

Comment: There's a potential security issue here: [check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Answer (score 0):

I always use this syntax and it works for me: `window.location = 'http://www.somesite.com';`